# Error, index out of range. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I wrote a Python3 script to solve a picoCTF challenge. I received the encrypted flag which is:
`cvpbPGS{c33xno00_1_f33_h_qrnqorrs}`
From its pattern, I thought it is encoded using caesar cipher. So I wrote this script:

```
alpha_lower = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
alpha_upper = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
        'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
text = 'cvpbPGSc33xno00_1_f33_h_qrnqorrs '

for iterator in range(len(alpha_lower)):
    temp = ''
    for char in text:
        if char.islower():
        
            ind = alpha_lower.index(char)
            this = ind + iterator
            
            while this > len(alpha_lower):
                this -= len(alpha_lower)
                
            temp += alpha_lower[this]
            
        elif char.isupper():
            ind = alpha_upper.index(char)
            that = ind + iterator
            
            while that > len(alpha_upper):
                that -= len(alpha_upper)

            temp += alpha_upper[that]
    print(temp)
```

I understand what the error means. I can't understand where the flaw is to fix. Thanks in advance.

Sorrym here is the error:

```
Desktop>python this.py 
cvpbPGScxnofhqrnqorrs  
dwqcQHTdyopgirsorpsst
exrdRIUezpqhjstpsqttu
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\this.py", line 18, in <module>
temp += alpha_lower[this]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the rror.

Comment: `this >= len(alpha_lower)` and `that >= len(alpha_upper)`?

Comment: The traceback shows us the line that failed.

Comment: Instead of that loop, use modulus: `this = (ind + iterator) % len(alpha_lower)`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. Dumb of me ngl.

Comment: @Ricardo I should have used %, right.

Comment: A little debugging would have worked wonders I think.  Was `this` negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your approach has an error because `ind + iterator` can have a maximum possible value of 50, which is more than `len(alpha_lower)`
- To fix it, you can use the modulus operator: `(ind + iterator) % len(alpha_lower)`
- There is a less complicated way to decode the Caesar cipher. Instead of using two different lists for upper and lower case characters, you should use the `ord()` and `chr()` functions to [manipulate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ord-function-python/) the unicode values.

Answer (score 1):

Why that break is simple :
If `this==len(alpha_lower)` then we won't enter your loop:
`while this > len(alpha_lower):`
And thus when trying `temp += alpha_lower[this]` it will return an error.
An index must be **strictly** inferior to the size of the array. Your condition should have been `while this >= len(alpha_lower):`.
As pointed out, a better method here is to use a modulus.